# File location issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, include

I'm having trouble putting data in safe locations.  What I want to do is allow my localhost to access the files to create my pages but prohibit all other access.

I started out trying to write a .htaccess file to prevent access to subfolders but read here that this was a poor way to do things  and was getting into a tangle anyway so, following advice, I tried moving the files out of the public_html directory:

The structure is:

```
bits_folder
    images
       testimage.jpg
    files
       testfile.php
public_html
    application
       callingfile.php
```

With this layout, I get error 404 if I try to access anything in bits_folder from the browser, as desired.  callingfile.php however does not seem able to access the testimage, but can include the php testfile.

callingfile.php:

```
require("../../bits_folder/files/testfile.php");  //works and displays file echo
<img src="../../bits_folder/images/testimage.jpg"  //gives broken image
```

both the files (testimage and testfile) are in the folders where they should be.

I am assuming that the reason for this behaviour is that the img is a http request after the page is served and will thus be denied but I am no server expert.  Is this the case?  Can this be overcome? Should I be doing this another way?

Comment: use absolute pathing, not relative, e.g in this case use <img src="/bits_folder/images/testimage.jpg"> if the bits_folder is on the highest directory-level

Comment: require is using relative path, that is why. the img is absolute. right click on broken image and you will see the path it has constructed.

Comment: amigura and @luk2302 thanks.  The image is being rendered with the www. included, which as 3ventic has answered below is the answer.  Thankyou to all who have offered advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only place scripts and images for PHP to use outside public_html. Images and other things that are as src or otherwise linked in HTML/JavaScript cause the browser to request those. The web server will refuse to serve them from outside the public directory.

Your browser will get access denied for `www.example.com/../../bits_folder/images/testimage.jpg`